# Dlib installation python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, dlib

Former marine grunt here! New to python and coding. Trying to install DLIB for python 2.7. I run the command `pip install dlib` and keep getting this error message:

> ```
> Collecting dlib
>   Using cached dlib-19.1.0.tar.gz 
> Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
>   Running setup.py bdist_wheel for dlib ... error
> Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\pickfl~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-4qhao2\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', \n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" 
> bdist_wheel -d c:\users\pickfl~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpcvgy9jpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
>   running bdist_wheel
>   running build
>   Detected Python architecture: 32bit
>   Detected platform: win32
>   Configuring cmake ...
>   -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
>   -- The C compiler identification is unknown
>   -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
>   CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
>     The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:
>       cl
>     is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
>     To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
>     that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
>     unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
>     Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).
>     Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
>     variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
>     the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
>   CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
>     The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:
>       cl
>     is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
>     To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
>     that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
>     unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
>     Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).
>     Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
>     variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
>     to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
>   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   See also "C:/Users/Pickflickr1/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-4qhao2/dlib/tools/python/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
>   See also "C:/Users/Pickflickr1/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-build-4qhao2/dlib/tools/python/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
>   error: cmake configuration failed!
>
>   ----------------------------------------   Failed building wheel for dlib
>
> Along with this:
>  Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\pickfl~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-4qhao2\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
> --record c:\users\pickfl~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-l8pcsq-record\install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\pickfl~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-4qhao2\dlib\
> ```

Any feedback or help would be great! Former jarhead so bear with me, thanks.

Comment: Is visual studio installed on your computer?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967887/solution-install-dlibpython-and-get-error

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
conda install -c menpo dlib=18.18
```

Comment: nice !but no need to specify version ,conda install -c menpo dlib

Answer (score 4):

First Install all the dependencies for dlib library :->

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip

sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config

sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libatlas-base-dev

sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev libboost-python-dev
```

Then Execute

```
pip install dlib
```

Enjoy computer-vision.....

“A lot of the future of search is going to be about pictures. Computer vision technology is going to be a big deal”

**Ben Silbermann**

Answer (score 3):

First you need to have pip installed. Then you can download the dlib python 2.7 version from "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dlib/18.17.100" website where you will get wheel of dlib. And then use normal procedure like pip install 'path to dlib wheel'.

For ex. f you have saved .whl file to downloads folder then type pip install C:\Users\XYZ\Downloads\dlib-18.17.100-cp27-none-win32.whl.

This will surely work. When I tried I didn't get any error and dlib got successfully installed.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me! I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows 7 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

The pip package might be broken or might not be updated. Anyway, download the dlib_master from :https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git

After that there is an easy guide for installation in python. Go to the folder containing  **setup.py** and then  open terminal or whatever and type 
sudo python setup.py install.